# Using jquery-ui-rails datepicker in an Ruby on Rails website. datepicker method not defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui-datepicker

I got this problem writing the website with Ruby on Rails.

```
bundle show
* jquery-ui-rails (4.0.1)
```

In app/assets/javascripts/application.js

```
//= require jquery.ui.datepicker
```

In app/assets/stylesheets/application.css

```
*= require jquery.ui.datepicker
```

In app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

And then in somepage.html.erb, I got

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#startdate").datepicker();
    $("#enddate").datepicker();
});
</script>
```

When running it, Chrome says that

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'datepicker'
```

I suppose that resource not being referred properly is the cause because the problem could be fixed by adding the follows into app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
```

These could be found at http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/. I saw demos having working datepickers without these codes. But I do not understand why it is not working in mine. Anyone got any suggestions? like something to add other than those I mentioned above?

Comment: I had the same problem yesterday. And it turned out that i had to put = require ./timepicker above everything else. Try that.

Comment: You don't have to include any other js but only one: `<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>` and make sure your assets folder contains jquery js within javascripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably because of either of the following:

1) You are including multiple javascript files in your `application.html.erb` which is leading to havoc when put altogether.

2) You are using some other javascript file that also using `$` just like jquery is using.
   Having two same symbols is the possible cause of getting `no method 'datepicker'` for the  jquery.

The alternative is to replace all the occurences of `$` with `jQuery`

OR

Just wrap your jquery code insode a block like the following:

```
jQuery(function($){
    //all jQuery code which uses $ should be here.
});
```